# OpenGl indices array

Tags: opengl, terrain

I have a class `terrain` which create a grid of `Quad`s. I do it like this

```
for(int z=0; z<_length;z++){
            for(int x=0; x<_width;x++){
                vertices.push_back(vec3((float)x*250, 0.f, (float)z*250));
    }
}
for(int z=0; z<(_length-1);++z){
    for(int x=0; x<(_width-1);++x){
        int index = z*_width+x; 
        Vertex _vertices[] = {
            Vertex(vertices.at(index),vec3(0, 0, 0)),
            Vertex(vertices.at(index+1),vec3(0, 0, 0)),
            Vertex(vertices.at(index+_width),vec3(0, 0, 0)),
            Vertex(vertices.at(index+1+_width),vec3(0,0,0))
        };

        unsigned short indices[]= {index,index + 1,index + 
            _width,index + 1,index +  _width,index +  _width + 1};
        Quad quad(_vertices, 4, indices, 6);
        squares.push_back(quad);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The vertices and the logic are correct, but the indices aren't, for some reason. here is the output for this code : 
[image]
But when I change this indices to this :

```
            unsigned short indices[]= {0,1,2,1,2,3};
```

It works great : 
[image]

The problem is I don't understand why this line

```
        unsigned short indices[]= {index,index + 1,index + 
            _width,index + 1,index +  _width,index +  _width + 1};
```

doesn't work. And if it worked, my grid would consume a lot less ressources. If someone could explain me why it doesn't work, It would be great, thanks you.
In case you need to know how I draw a Quad, here is the code :

```
class Quad{
public:
    Quad(Vertex *_vertices, int _n, unsigned short * _indices, unsigned short _numIndices){
        for(int i=0; i < _numIndices; i++){
            indices.push_back(_indices[i]);
        } 

        for(int i=0; i<_n; i++){
            vec3 v = vec3(_vertices[i].position, _lengthPower);
            position.push_back(v);                     
        }
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVertexArray);
        glBindVertexArray(mVertexArray);

        glGenBuffers(1, &mPositionBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mPositionBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec3)*position.size(), position.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

        glGenBuffers(1, &mIndicesBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned short)*indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    }

    void draw(){
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mPositionBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIndicesBuffer);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    }
    ~Quad(){

    }
private:

    std::vector<unsigned short> indices; 
    std::vector<vec3> position; 
    GLuint mVertexArray; 
    GLuint mPositionBuffer; 
    GLuint mIndicesBuffer; 
};
```

I'm using, OpenGL, glm, glfw etc.

Comment: What is the `indices.size()` size value in your draw method? And if your indices are of length 6 (= `unsigned short indices[]= {0,1,2,1,2,3}; `), why is it working? Or you draw each quad in separate VBO when you use those working indices above?

Comment: It should be 6, it's a vector I fill in the constructor. Something wrong with it ?

Comment: Yes, each quad has its own VBO.

Comment: But every VBO store an array of vertices. `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec3)*position.size(), position.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

Comment: Well... I thought you put all terrain vertices in same VBO(I should read better :) ) Why would you wanted separate VBOs for each quad? It would completely destroy performance(recommended size is 1-4MB). You can have separate VBO for each quad, but as far as I know, only one VBO can be be source for one draw call. (if you dont count multidraws, gs or non-vbo subustitutions like texture arrays)

Comment: I see. I'm using multiple VBOs because I've implemented an LOD which subdivide each qua 4 times. So I thought It'd be better, but your way seems to be the right way to do it, I'm gonna try it right now. I'll let you know if it works, so you can make another answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

The call `glDrawElements(..., indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);` tells your GPU roughly following:

```
for(unsigned short i = 0 /*last parameter*/; i < indices.size(); i += 3 /*3 vertices/triangle*/ )
{
   drawTriangle(VBO[indices[i]], VBO[indices[i + 1]], VBO[indices[i + 2]] );
}
```

Do you see what is wrong now? If the value of `indices[i]` is higher than your size of VBO, it is a problem.
Moreover, for VBO it is [recommended](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices) to have around 1-4MB of vertices in it - only 4 vertices/VBO will very likely kill your performance. You might be interested in [instancing](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html) instead.

*big edit reason: cant read right(solved in comments)*

Comment: So it's impossible to render the terrain in separate buffers ? In other words, it's impossible for triangles to share vertices if they're not int the same buffer ? If not, then I really didn't get your answer. Thanks for your time, I really appreciate

Comment: @R00t Well... I thought you put all terrain vertices in same VBO(I should read better :) ) Why would you wanted separate VBOs for each quad? It would completely destroy performance(recommended size is 1-4MB). You can have separate VBO for each quad, but as far as I know, only one VBO can be be source for one draw call. (if you dont count multidraws, gs or non-vbo subustitutions like texture arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Cause each quad have it's own VBO all the index in the VBO will go from zero to three. But you are sending index from 0 to _width*_height as you were indexing the original array of vertexes (and not the subset you pass in each VBO). Basically you are rendering random memory.